# Requirements for ability to reproduce

Tags: reproduction

In my (albeit basic) biology classes in the past, we've learned about how, to reproduce, two organisms must have the same number of chromosomes. This has been verified by a few other websites I found. So- I've heard about various genetic disorders in which people can have fewer or more chromosomes than usual. For example, if a person had tetrasomy, they would have two extra chromosomes (48 in total). Chimpanzees also have 48. 
Therefore:

If, hypothetically, a person with tetrasomy and a chimp's sex cells were combined, would it create anything?

If not, what are the other requirements for creating a baby organism besides the parents having the same number of chromosomes?

Comment: You seem to be more interested in the ability to mate with another individual than to reproduce. A lot of the reproductive efforts out there does not involve any mating (asexual reproduction). You might want to clarify that in your title. Also, you might want to highlight in your title that you are interested in differences in chromosomal number among the two mating individuals.

Comment: Can you please link to the `few other websites [you] found`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ability to produce offspring has more to do with the compatibility of the chromosomes than the number. This is why hybrid species (such as mules) are able to survive (but are infertile). If you want to learn about why hybrids are infertile [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/16922/why-are-hybrids-infertile) is stackexchange question about.

Although, this would all be dependent on weather gametogenesis could occur with the tetrasomy. But as seen [here](http://www.fertstert.org/article/S0015-0282(06)03067-6/fulltext) with Down syndrome, it can be successful.